# Cell locations changing with filtered data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have some data that is being filtered. I only have a dollar value and a % of total. I am using the filters to sort the data from largest to smallest in regards to the % of Total value.

Below the data set I have a total spend calculation and then I have a Pass Through formula. The Pass Through function is the Subtotal minus a few line items.

My problem is that Pass Through function reads something like `=SUM(A1:A10)-A3-A5`. When I sort the data then the cells themselves move but my formula doesn't adjust. The amount changes and is now wrong.

Is there anyway so that my formula "follows" the amounts so that it's always correct no matter what sorting I do?

Comment: Show an example of your sheet, Please?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to add a "helper" column of 0's and 1's to your table and use SUMPRODUCT. Here is an example where Cell `A11` contains your formula `=SUM(A2:A10)-A3-A5` and Cell `C11` contains a modified formula `=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A10,C2:C10)`

Without sorting ...

[image]

Sorted ascending ...

[image]

Of course, with more complex formula, it can be more complicated to perform.